# Increasing open files

Tags: files

I've follow the instructions what I've found here, and I saw it in a lot of posts.

The `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
*         hard    nofile      500000
*         soft    nofile      500000
root      hard    nofile      500000
root      soft    nofile      500000
```

The end of tye `sysctl.conf`

```
fs.file-max = 2097152
```

Restart the machine and after all here is the `ulimit`

```
root@my-machine:/etc# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31333
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31333
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Can somebody tell me why open files is 1024 and my changes why do not effects?

Comment: Maybe you have this problem  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108603/do-changes-in-etc-security-limits-conf-require-a-reboot

Comment: @user1452962 As I sad, I rebooted. I do not understand what you would like to suggest with it.